# How can I check whether a method is a class method or a static method in a metaclass?

Tags: python, static-methods, metaclass, class-method

Here is a very simple `Base` class, which contains a static method and a class method:

```
class Base():

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print("Base.f")

    @classmethod
    def g(cls):
        print("Base.g")

    def h(self):
        print("Base.h")
```

If a class is to be derived from `Base` and override either `f` or `g` then, the `staticmethod` and `classmethod` decorators need to be used again on the overriding methods.

```
class A(Base):

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print("A.f")

class B(Base):

    @classmethod
    def g(cls):
        print("B.g")
```

So, at first I thought I would create a metaclass that automatically makes `f` a `staticmethod` and `g` a `staticmethod`.

```
class BaseMeta(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        if 'f' in namespace: cls.f = staticmethod(cls.f)
        if 'g' in namespace: cls.g = classmethod(cls.g)
```

Now the rest of the classes don't need to use `staticmethod` and `classmethod` explicitly.

```
class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):

    def f():
        print("Base.f")

    def g(cls):
        print("Base.g")

    def h(self):
        print("Base.h")

class A(Base):

    def f():
        print("A.f")

class B(Base):

    def g(cls):
        print("B.g")
```

This works, but I don't like how it looks. Now, I realize that the `staticmethod` and `classmethod` decorators *should* be explicitly used (after all, explicit is better than implicit, isn't it?)

So I thought I could keep the metaclass, but this time instead of *enforcing* the decorators, I should just *check* whether or not they have been used and throw an exception if they haven't.

```
class BaseMeta(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        # check if cls.f is a static method
        if not inspect.isfunction(cls.f):
            raise Exception("f should be a static method")
        # check if cls.g is a static method
        if not (inspect.ismethod(cls.g) and cls.g.__self__ == cls):
            raise Exception("g should be a class method")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It seems that in the metaclasse's `__init__`, everything is considered to be just a function (just printing `cls.f` and `cls.g` makes this apparent).

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: In Python explicit is not \necessarily\ better than implicit. Consider that EAFP (easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) is considered Pythonic and higher level thinking is encouraged over computing details as examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if not (inspect.ismethod(cls.g) and cls.g.__self__ == cls):
    raise Exception("g should be a class method")
```

works fine, but this:

```
if not inspect.isfunction(cls.f):
    raise Exception("f should be a static method")
```

doesn't, because on Python 3, `cls.f` will be the `f` function whether or not the `staticmethod` decorator was applied. (On Python 2, it would have been an unbound method object without the decorator.)

---

Instead of accessing `cls.f` or `cls.g` and trying to work out what kind of descriptor you went through based on the results of the descriptor protocol, bypass the descriptor protocol and access the raw contents of the class definition's namespace:

```
if 'f' in namespace and not isinstance(namespace['f'], staticmethod):
    whatever()
if 'g' in namespace and not isinstance(namespace['g'], classmethod):
    whatever()
```

Comment: I tested `inspect.isfunction` and it returned `True` for all methods (`f`, `g` and `h`). I also tested `inspect.ismethod` and it returned `False` for all these methods. These tests actually *do* work if you try them after the class has been created, but they don't seem to work in the metaclass.

Comment: @GeorgeBoukeas: Could you clarify what the `XX` was supposed to represent there?

Comment: @GeorgeBoukeas: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/288YGK) `ismethod` returns `True` as expected for the classmethod.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it seems that trying to check whether `cls.f` or `cls.g` are static or class methods in the metaclass is pointless, they don't seem to be *bound* yet.

However, having used the `staticmethod` or `classmethod` decorator on a method must surely have left its mark on it. I played around, and eventually found that what I originally wanted to do can be implemented as follows:

```
class BaseMeta(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        # check if cls.f is a static method
        if 'f' in namespace and not isinstance(namespace['f'], staticmethod):
            raise Exception(cls.__name__ + ".f should be a static method")
        # check if cls.g is a class method
        if 'g' in namespace and not isinstance(namespace['g'], classmethod):
            raise Exception(cls.__name__ + ".g should be a class method")
```

So, the answer to the original question is:

> Checking whether a method has been decorated with `staticmethod` or `classmethod` is possible in a metaclass, by retrieving the method *from the namespace* and checking whether it is an instance of `'staticmethod'` or `'classmethod'`.

Comment: You don't need to look at the `__name__`. `isinstance(whatever, staticmethod)` and `isinstance(whatever, classmethod)` would work fine.

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly more elegant. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.2+, you can use [`inspect.getattr_static`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getattr_static):

> Retrieve attributes without triggering dynamic lookup via the descriptor protocol, **getattr**() or **getattribute**().

Example:

```py
import inspect


class A:
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        pass

    @classmethod
    def g(cls):
        pass

    def r():
        pass


a = A()
print(isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(a, "f"), staticmethod))
print(isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(A, "f"), staticmethod))
print(isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(a, "g"), classmethod))
print(isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(A, "g"), classmethod))
print(isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(a, "r"), classmethod))
print(isinstance(inspect.getattr_static(A, "r"), staticmethod))
```

Will output:

```
True
True
True
True
False
False
```